# utc string to unix time conversion python

Tags: python, unix, timestamp, utc, datetime-conversion

I have a list of UTC time stamps stored as string format as follows:

```
'20170124T1815'
```

Is there a function in python to convert these strings to unix time? I have tried:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
(datetime.datetime.utcnow('20170127T2131').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

but these have not been working for me as these functions are not meant to take arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the string '20170124T1815' to a datetime instance:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('20170124T1815', '%Y%m%dT%H%M')
```

Then use `timestamp()` method to convert to UNIX time:

```
ut = dt.timestamp()
# -> 1485281700.0
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> datetime.timestamp()
>
> Return POSIX timestamp corresponding to the *datetime* instance. The return value is a float similar to that returned by `time.time()`.

**EDIT**

For Python version < 3.3, you can use:

```
ut = (dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Or, you can use:

```
import time

ut = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
```

*Thanks to Peter DeGlopper*

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting an error saying AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: I have only imported datetime

Comment: `timestamp()` is new in version 3.3. Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: For versions without `.timestamp()` I prefer `time.mktime(dt.timetuple())`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yes, I only copy and adapt the solution presented in the documentation.

Comment: `(dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()` returns timestamp from UTC (good) and keeps subsecond precision, `time.mktime(dt.timetuple())` returns timestamp from local time (bad) and truncates to seconds.